# Why doesn't this send a message box when pressing a after pressing b?

Tags: autohotkey

```
a::
 if GetKeyState(b) {
   MsgBox, Enter key is pressed!
}
```

Why doesn't this send a message box when pressing a after pressing b? Isn't this how GetKeyState() works?

Comment: Potential cross-network duplicate? [GetKeyState breaks if a new key is pressed](https://superuser.com/questions/1619443/autohotkey-getkeystate-breaks-if-a-new-key-is-pressed)